# Wrapping every 5 divs with a wrapper div

Tags: jquery

I have a bunch of divs inside a wrapper and want to wrap every 5 with a new parent. So markup starts like:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class=child"></div>
  <div class=child"></div>
  <div class=child"></div>
  <div class=child"></div>
  <div class=child"></div>
</div>
```

Then I have an ajax load more button which pulls in another 5 divs inside the "wrapper" div so markup looks like:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class=child"></div>
  <div class=child"></div>
  <div class=child"></div>
  <div class=child"></div>
  <div class=child"></div>
  <div class=child"></div>
  <div class=child"></div>
  <div class=child"></div>
  <div class=child"></div>
  <div class=child"></div>
</div>
```

At this point - I want to wrap every 5 divs in a new parent so markup becomes:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="newParent">
    <div class=child"></div>
    <div class=child"></div>
    <div class=child"></div>
    <div class=child"></div>
    <div class=child"></div>
  </div>
   <div class="newParent">
    <div class=child"></div>
    <div class=child"></div>
    <div class=child"></div>
    <div class=child"></div>
    <div class=child"></div>
  </div>    
</div>
```

Then if ajax load more button is clicked again, new child divs will get added to the parent "wrapper" which should again get wrapped inside the "newparent" div...

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="newParent">
    <div class=child"></div>
    <div class=child"></div>
    <div class=child"></div>
    <div class=child"></div>
    <div class=child"></div>
  </div>
   <div class="newParent">
    <div class=child"></div>
    <div class=child"></div>
    <div class=child"></div>
    <div class=child"></div>
    <div class=child"></div>
  </div> 
  <div class="newParent">
    <div class=child"></div>
    <div class=child"></div>
  </div>    
</div>
```

This works using my code below... BUT.. the code I am using wraps the "new parent" inside another version so I get unwanted nested divs... Any help suggestions on what I am not doing right here please?

```
var $span = $(".wrapper .child");
    for (var i = 0; i < $span.length; i += 6) {
    var $div = $("<div/>", {
    class: 'newParent'
  });
  $span.slice(i, i + 6).wrapAll($div);
  }
```

I guess I need a statement to say only apply this logic to immediate children "child" divs in the parent "wrapper" div?

Comment: `$(".wrapper .child");` --> `$(".wrapper > .child");`. This change will target only the `.child` elements which have been appended directly to `.wrapper` and have not already been wrapped following a previous AJAX request

Comment: Legend! Thanks so much

Comment: Glad it helped - I added it as an answer for you

Comment: One thing actually.... using the jQuery code - for some reason on the 2nd load more click makes the first "newParent" div has 6 children....

Comment: Could you please add more of the jQuery code to the question - including the AJAX request and how you invoke the logic above

Comment: Dont worry sorted it - by changing the values of 6 to 5... doh!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `$(".wrapper .child")` to `$(".wrapper > .child")`.

This change will target only the `.child` elements which have been appended directly to `.wrapper` and have not already been wrapped after a previous AJAX request